# How can i persist my data in docker/postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I know there are probably many ways to do this.  What I am looking for is a way to do it using (preferably) only my DockerFile and one container.

Here is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ENV POSTGRES_USER=myuser
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Here is the command I used to build this container:

```
docker built -t my_db .
```

And here is the command that I use to run the container:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 my_db
```

What I would like to do is have the data stored in the container if possible, but I don't seem to understand how or where postgres stores it's data.  I saw on another stack overflow post that postgres will store it by default in /var/lib/postgresql/data however when I look in that folder I see nothing.  I can however verify that postgres is running because I am using a client called teamSQL and from that client I can create tables and insert/read data.

I can also verify that when i stop the container and restart the data is definitely not persisted.

Note: this is running in OSx but I don't think that is relevant.

Comment: Did you read the [Postgres Docker Hub Page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), specifically the `Where to Store Data` section?

Comment: Nope, but it looks very useful.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Docker volumes, so when you stop your container, data will persist on host machine, and when you start container again data will be mounted to it

```
docker volume create pgdata
docker run -p 5432:5432 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data my_db
```